# How to use the WebElementPromise in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Disclaimer: I only fell in love with promises when `async/await` came along.

I am a bit puzzled by this:

```
/**
 * WebElementPromise is a promise that will be fulfilled with a WebElement.
 * This serves as a forward proxy on WebElement, allowing calls to be
 * scheduled without directly on this instance before the underlying
 * WebElement has been fulfilled. In other words, the following two statements
 * are equivalent:
 *
 *     driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'}).click();
 *     driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'}).then(function(el) {
 *       return el.click();
 *     });
```

The second statement, with the `then()`, makes sense: the promise is resolved with the element, and `then` is then run.

But... what about `driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'}).click();`? What is *actually* going on here? `driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'})` returns an unfulfilled promise. As far as I knew, a promise only has `then()` and `catch()`. What's with `click()`?

And what's with the explanation, talking about a "forward proxy"? I am lost!

Comment: `driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'})` returns a `WebElement`. "Promise" represents the value `return el.click();`

Comment: @GalAbra I am not sure I follow you. I was sure `driver.findElement({id: 'my-button'})` returned a promise...?

Answer (score 1):

Because `WebElementPromise` extends `WebElement`,it inherits `click()` from `WebElement`; And it implements `then()` and `catch()`, so you can use as promise also.

[image]

more details to see source code [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f16c3216dfc4b4fb91e10049c8603f6285774f76/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js)